# update-locale: Error: invalid locale settings: LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Tags: ubuntu, locale

I have done nothing to locales but one day I found problem for locales:
Your system needs to support the en_US.UTF-8 locale.

I'm not able to set locale to en_US.UTF-8 with "dpkg-reconfigure locales ":

[image]

I have tried a lot, like adding below to "/etc/default/locale":

```
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

But nothing helps!
I don't what's the problem, can anyone have similar problem here?

Answer (score 2):

As root, edit /etc/locale.gen
Make sure it contains this line, *uncommented* (no #):

> en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8

Then run locale-gen (as root).